# Weird behaviour of ListView scrollbars

Tags: android, listview, typeface

I have a ListView which I want to populate with items each of which contains only one `TextView`. The thing about these `TextView`-s is that they need to use custom font (not the one of three built-in fonts). I can not set custom font (typeface) via XML so the only way to do it is call `tv.setTypeface()` for all TextView-s in the `getView()` method of my Adapter.

Now the problem is that the font I want to use has the pretty much different line spacing (by default) so the resulting text appears larger than the same text rendered using default font (providing we use the same `textSize` for two fonts). This particulary affects the way `ListView` measures the overall size (height) of my text (and thus the size of scrollbar) thinking that text is rendered using default typeface (while in reality it is not).

When I scroll my `ListView` up or down the overall size of the text is constanly recalculated resulting in scrollbar changing its length (which looks weird). I wonder if there a way to tell `ListView` to use my custom font **before** the call to `getView()` method (i.e. during text measurement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the thing I am trying to achieve is impossible. Simply because there is no list item exist except for those which are visible at the moment. So the ListView does know nothing about the height of its items **before** they were inflated and populated with text.

What it can do - is only to make assumptions based on the item layout supplied to LIstView upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

It is default behaviour of ListView. Try to set [`smoothScrollbar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3asmoothScrollbar) to `true`. In XML:

```
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
```

or in code:

```
listView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but this does not help.
ListView still uses old (default) font for calculations